# Keras, tensorflow import error

Tags: keras

Need help.
(I also checked thread: How do I install Keras and Theano in Anaconda Python on Windows?)

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
```

Although I have done everything explained in this thread I keep getting an error for the above prompts.

The error message when I place the cursor on the statements:

```
Unable to resolve "keras.models". Intellisense may be missing for this module
Unable to resolve "keras.layers.core". Intellisense may be missing for this module
Unable to resolve "keras.layers.recurrent". Intellisense may be missing for this module
```

I un-istalled, re-installed, deleted theano, updated keras. everything but nothing changed.

Could anyone come up with a possible solution?

thank you

Comment: Are you sure you're activating the right environment? Are you using Jupyter Notebook? Which python version is your notebook pointing to? Is it the same as where you installed keras and theano? (See with `import sys` and `print(sys.executable)`.

Comment: for the the process you explained I did the following: 1-open command window of anaconda 2-type 'python' 3- type 'import sys' 4- type 'print(sys.executable)' 5- dont get any reply from system